# Finding middle value in c++

Tags: c++

There's a part of my code that I got confused about. First I tried to find the min and max value of 4 given numbers(randomly). Then I need to find the average value of middle numbers, here's my code, any help will be appreciated thanks!

I think I am supposed to use min and max functions I did in the first part? but I am not sure how to do that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int result;

int min(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    result = a;
    if (b < result) result = b;
    if (c < result) result = c;
    if (d < result) result = d;
    return result;
}

int max(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int result = a; 
    if (b > result) result = b;
    if (c > result) result = c;
    if (d > result) result = d;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int Min,Max;
    Min = min(2,6,3,4);
    cout << " The result for minimum is " << Min <<endl;
    Max = max(2,6,3,4);
    cout << " The result for maximum is " << Max;
}

/**
  Computes the average of the middle values of four given values
  (that is, without the largest and smallest value).
  Hint: Use the given min function. You may also want to define a
  max helper function or take advantage of the fact that max can be
  computed from the min of the negative values.
**/

/** things got confused after this...the first part is actually finished with the help from my other question **/

    int mv1;

double middle(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int  mv1=a;
    if(a<=b)
        return a;
}

int main1()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int n;
    int md;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout << "Enter another number:  ";
    cin>>y;
    cout << "Enter the third number:  ";
    cin>>z;
    cout << "Enter the fourth number:  ";
    cin>>n;

    md=middle(x,y,z,n);
    cout << endl<<"middle is "<<md <<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: It’s your homework.

Comment: Well you could use the min and max functions to eliminate two of the numbers in your set of four and the remaining two numbers are the middle two.

Comment: Have you been taught about arrays yet? This task would be easier if your four numbers were in an array.

Comment: I havne't learn that john, this is only my second homework to be honest.

Comment: What do you mean with the middle value?

Comment: I am guessing it's just the median, but the homework says" the average of middle values", so...

Comment: @YunxiaoJia that's not very useful homework indeed... If you want to learn proper c++ programming, start learning the stl. I put you an example creating a vector and sorting it to obtain the median. The proper way to do it would be to use `nth_element` algorithm, but because this is a simple example with 4 elements, you could just sort them and pick the values you need.

Answer (score 4):

You should start learning the standard template library, you could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

double median(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    std::vector<int> v{a,b,c,d};
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    return static_cast<double>(v[1]+v[2])/2;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "median of 1,2,3,4: " << median(1,2,3,4) << "\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
middle of 1,2,3,4: 2.5
```

Using the stl algorithms will make your code more expressive and easier to understand. I would recommend you to learning them from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

do some kind of sorting on your numbers first,then you will get minimum and maximum easily.After that just add middle numbers and subtract it with total count of middle numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have four numbers you can do:

```
float median = (sum(...) - min(...) - max(...)) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulate the [min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) function values:

```
  int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return std::max(std::max(a,b),                   
                                                        std::max(c, d));
                                      }
  int min(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return std::min(std::min(a,b),                   
                                                        std::min(c, d));
                                      }
  int mid = ((a+b+c+d) - max(a,b,c,d) - min(a,b,c,d))/2;
```

Or if you are on c++11 you can do this  as:

```
 auto values = {a,b,c,d};
 decltype(values.begin()) mn, mx;
 std::tie(mn, mx) = std::minmax_element(values.begin(), values.end());
 auto median = (std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0) - *mn - *mx) / 2;
```

In action here: https://ideone.com/69nRvo